# FFT algorithm in MATLAB

Tags: c, matlab, fft

I'm looking to implement an FFT algorithm on microcontrollers so I want to simulate the codes before actually using it

I got 2 examples which I converted to matlab codes but the result just isn't what I'm expected

Here are the codes:

```
function [ H ] = fft_2( g )
%FFT2 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

NUMDATA = length(g);
NUMPOINTS = NUMDATA/2;
N = NUMPOINTS;
% for(k=0; k<N; k++)
% {
% IA[k].imag = -(short)(16383.0*(-cos(2*pi/(double)(2*N)*(double)k)));
% IA[k].real = (short)(16383.0*(1.0 - sin(2*pi/(double)(2*N)*(double)k)));
% IB[k].imag = -(short)(16383.0*(cos(2*pi/(double)(2*N)*(double)k)));
% IB[k].real = (short)(16383.0*(1.0 + sin(2*pi/(double)(2*N)*(double)k)));
% }
for k=0:(N-1)
    IA(k+1,2) = -floor(16383.0*(-cos(2*pi/(2*N)*k)));
    IA(k+1,1) = floor(16383.0*(1.0 - sin(2*pi/(2*N)*k)));
    IB(k+1,2) = -floor(16383.0*(cos(2*pi/(2*N)*k)));
    IB(k+1,1) = floor(16383.0*(1.0 + sin(2*pi/(2*N)*k)));
end
% Note, IA(k) is the complex conjugate of A(k) and IB(k) is the complex conjugate of
% B(k).
%  *********************************************************************************/
% #include <math.h>
% #include ”params1.h”
% #include ”params.h”
% extern short g[];
% void dft(int, COMPLEX *);
% void split(int, COMPLEX *, COMPLEX *, COMPLEX *, COMPLEX *);
% main()
% {
% int n, k;
% COMPLEX x[NUMPOINTS+1]; /* array of complex DFT data */
% COMPLEX A[NUMPOINTS]; /* array of complex A coefficients */
% COMPLEX B[NUMPOINTS]; /* array of complex B coefficients */
% COMPLEX IA[NUMPOINTS]; /* array of complex A* coefficients */
% COMPLEX IB[NUMPOINTS]; /* array of complex B* coefficients */
% COMPLEX G[2*NUMPOINTS]; /* array of complex DFT result */
% for(k=0; k<NUMPOINTS; k++)
for k=0:(NUMPOINTS-1)
    % {
    % A[k].imag = (short)(16383.0*(-cos(2*pi/(double)(2*NUMPOINTS)*(double)k)));
    % A[k].real = (short)(16383.0*(1.0 - sin(2*pi/(double)(2*NUMPOINTS)*(double)k)));
    % B[k].imag = (short)(16383.0*(cos(2*pi/(double)(2*NUMPOINTS)*(double)k)));
    % B[k].real = (short)(16383.0*(1.0 + sin(2*pi/(double)(2*NUMPOINTS)*(double)k)));
    % IA[k].imag = -A[k].imag;
    % IA[k].real = A[k].real;
    % IB[k].imag = -B[k].imag;
    % IB[k].real = B[k].real;
    % }
    A(k+1, 2) = floor(16383.0*(-cos(2*pi/(2*NUMPOINTS)*k)));
    A(k+1, 1) = floor(16383.0*(1.0 - sin(2*pi/(2*NUMPOINTS)*k)));
    B(k+1, 2) = floor(16383.0*(cos(2*pi/(2*NUMPOINTS)*k)));
    B(k+1, 1) = floor(16383.0*(1.0 + sin(2*pi/(2*NUMPOINTS)*k)));
    IA(k+1, 2) = -A(k+1, 2);
    IA(k+1, 1) = A(k+1, 1);
    IB(k+1, 2) = -B(k+1, 2);
    IB(k+1, 1) = B(k+1, 1);
end
% /* Forward DFT */
% /* From the 2N point real sequence, g(n), for the N-point complex sequence, x(n) */
% for (n=0; n<NUMPOINTS; n++)
% {
for n=0:(NUMPOINTS-1)
    % x[n].imag = g[2*n + 1]; /* x2(n) = g(2n + 1) */
    % x[n].real = g[2*n]; /* x1(n) = g(2n) */
    % }
    x(n+1,2)=g(2*n + 1+1);
    x(n+1,1)=g(2*n +1);
end
% /* Compute the DFT of x(n) to get X(k) -> X(k) = DFT{x(n)} */
% dft(NUMPOINTS, x);
% void dft(int N, COMPLEX *X)
% {
% int n, k;
% double arg;
% int Xr[1024];
% int Xi[1024];
% short Wr, Wi;
% for(k=0; k<N; k++)
% {
N=NUMPOINTS;
for k=0:(N-1)
    % Xr[k] = 0;
    % Xi[k] = 0;
    Xr(k+1)=0;
    Xi(k+1)=0;
    % for(n=0; n<N; n++)
    % {
    for n=0:(N-1)
        % arg =(2*PI*k*n)/N;
        % Wr = (short)((double)32767.0 * cos(arg));
        % Wi = (short)((double)32767.0 * sin(arg));
        % Xr[k] = Xr[k] + X[n].real * Wr + X[n].imag * Wi;
        % Xi[k] = Xi[k] + X[n].imag * Wr – X[n].real * Wi;
        arg = (2*pi*k*n)/N;
        Wr = floor(32767*cos(arg));
        Wi = floor(32767*sin(arg));
        Xr(k+1) = Xr(k+1)+x(n+1,1)*Wr+x(n+1,2)*Wi;
        Xi(k+1) = Xr(k+1)+x(n+1,2)*Wr-x(n+1,1)*Wi;
        % }
        % }
    end
end
% for (k=0;k<N;k++)
% {
for k=0:(N-1)
    % X[k].real = (short)(Xr[k]>>15);
    % X[k].imag = (short)(Xi[k]>>15);
    x(k+1,1)=floor(Xr(k+1)/pow2(15));
    x(k+1,2)=floor(Xi(k+1)/pow2(15));
    % }
    % }
end
% /* Because of the periodicity property of the DFT, we know that X(N+k)=X(k). */
% x[NUMPOINTS].real = x[0].real;
%  x[NUMPOINTS].imag = x[0].imag;
x(NUMPOINTS+1,1)=x(1,1);
x(NUMPOINTS+1,2)=x(1,2);
%  /* The split function performs the additional computations required to get
%  G(k) from X(k). */
% split(NUMPOINTS, x, A, B, G);
% void split(int N, COMPLEX *X, COMPLEX *A, COMPLEX *B, COMPLEX *G)
% {
% int k;
%  int Tr, Ti;
% for (k=0; k<N; k++)
% {
for k=0:(NUMPOINTS-1)
    % Tr = (int)X[k].real * (int)A[k].real – (int)X[k].imag * (int)A[k].imag +
    % (int)X[N–k].real * (int)B[k].real + (int)X[N–k].imag * (int)B[k].imag;
    Tr = x(k+1,1)*A(k+1,1)-x(k+1,2)*A(k+1,2)+x(NUMPOINTS-k+1,1)*B(k+1,1)+x(NUMPOINTS-k+1,2)*B(k+1,2);
    % G[k].real = (short)(Tr>>15);
    G(k+1,1)=floor(Tr/pow2(15));
    % Ti = (int)X[k].imag * (int)A[k].real + (int)X[k].real * (int)A[k].imag +
    % (int)X[N–k].real * (int)B[k].imag – (int)X[N–k].imag * (int)B[k].real;
    Ti = x(k+1,2)*A(k+1,1)+x(k+1,1)*A(k+1,2)+x(NUMPOINTS-k+1,1)*B(k+1,2)-x(NUMPOINTS-k+1,2)*B(k+1,1);
    % G[k].imag = (short)(Ti>>15);
    G(k+1,2)=floor(Ti/pow2(15));
    % }
end
% }
% /* Use complex conjugate symmetry properties to get the rest of G(k) */
% G[NUMPOINTS].real = x[0].real - x[0].imag;
% G[NUMPOINTS].imag = 0;
% for (k=1; k<NUMPOINTS; k++)
% {
% G[2*NUMPOINTS-k].real = G[k].real;
% G[2*NUMPOINTS-k].imag = -G[k].imag;
% }
G(NUMPOINTS+1,1) = x(1,1) - x(1,2);
G(NUMPOINTS+1,2) = 0;
for k=1:(NUMPOINTS-1)
    G(2*NUMPOINTS-k+1,1) = G(k+1,1);
    G(2*NUMPOINTS-k+1,2) = -G(k+1,2);
end
for k=1:(NUMDATA)
    H(k)=sqrt(G(k,1)*G(k,1)+G(k,2)*G(k,2));
end
end
```

Another one:

```
function [ fr, fi ] = fix_fft( fr, fi )
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
N_WAVE  =    1024;    % full length of Sinewave[]
LOG2_N_WAVE = 10;     % log2(N_WAVE)
m = nextpow2(length(fr));

% void fix_fft(short fr[], short fi[], short m)
% {
%   long int mr = 0, nn, i, j, l, k, istep, n, shift;
mr=0;
%   short qr, qi, tr, ti, wr, wi;
%
%   n = 1 << m;
n = pow2(m);
%   nn = n - 1;
nn = n-1;
%
%   /* max FFT size = N_WAVE */
%   //if (n > N_WAVE) return -1;
%
%   /* decimation in time - re-order data */
%   for (m=1; m<=nn; ++m)
for m=1:nn
    %   {
    %       l = n;
    l=n;

    %       do
    %       {
    %           l >>= 1;
    %       } while (mr+l > nn);
    not_done = true;
    while(mr+l>nn || not_done)
        l=floor(l/2);
        not_done=false;
    end

    %
    %       mr = (mr & (l-1)) + l;
    mr = (mr & (l-1)) + l;
    %       if (mr <= m) continue;
    if (mr <= m)
        continue
    end
    %
    %       tr = fr[m];
    %       fr[m] = fr[mr];
    %       fr[mr] = tr;
    %       ti = fi[m];
    %       fi[m] = fi[mr];
    %       fi[mr] = ti;

    tr = fr(m+1);
    fr(m+1) = fr(mr+1);
    fr(mr+1) = tr;
    ti = fi(m+1);
    fi(m+1) = fi(mr+1);
    fi(mr+1) = ti;
    %   }
end
%
%   l = 1;
%   k = LOG2_N_WAVE-1;
l=1;
k = LOG2_N_WAVE-1;
%
%   while (l < n)
%   {
while (l < n)
    %       /*
    %         fixed scaling, for proper normalization --
    %         there will be log2(n) passes, so this results
    %         in an overall factor of 1/n, distributed to
    %         maximize arithmetic accuracy.
    %
    %         It may not be obvious, but the shift will be
    %         performed on each data point exactly once,
    %         during this pass.
    %       */
    %
    %       // Variables for multiplication code
    %       long int c;
    %       short b;
    %
    %       istep = l << 1;
    istep = l*2;
    %       for (m=0; m<l; ++m)
    %       {
    for m=0:(l-1)
        %           j = m << k;
        %           /* 0 <= j < N_WAVE/2 */
        %           wr =  Sinewave[j+N_WAVE/4];
        %           wi = -Sinewave[j];
        j = m*(pow2( k));
        wr = sin((j+N_WAVE/4)*2*pi/N_WAVE)*32768;
        wi = -sin(j*2*pi/1024)*32768;
        %
        %           wr >>= 1;
        %           wi >>= 1;
        wr = floor(wr/2);
        wi = floor(wi/2);
        %
        %           for (i=m; i<n; i+=istep)
        %           {
        i=m;
        while(i<n)
            %               j = i + l;
            j = i+l;
            %
            %               // Here I unrolled the multiplications to prevent overhead
            %               // for procedural calls (we don't need to be clever about
            %               // the actual multiplications since the pic has an onboard
            %               // 8x8 multiplier in the ALU):
            %
            %               // tr = FIX_MPY(wr,fr[j]) - FIX_MPY(wi,fi[j]);
            %               c = ((long int)wr * (long int)fr[j]);
            %               c = c >> 14;
            %               b = c & 0x01;
            %               tr = (c >> 1) + b;
            c = wr * fr(j+1);
            c = floor(c / pow2(14));
            b = c & 1;
            tr = floor(c /2) + b;
            %
            %               c = ((long int)wi * (long int)fi[j]);
            %               c = c >> 14;
            %               b = c & 0x01;
            %               tr = tr - ((c >> 1) + b);
            c = wi * fi(j+1);
            c = floor(c / pow2(14));
            b = c & 1;
            tr = tr - (floor((c/2)) + b);
            %
            %               // ti = FIX_MPY(wr,fi[j]) + FIX_MPY(wi,fr[j]);
            %               c = ((long int)wr * (long int)fi[j]);
            %               c = c >> 14;
            %               b = c & 0x01;
            %               ti = (c >> 1) + b;
            c = wr*fi(j+1);
            c = floor(c / pow2(14));
            b = c & 1;
            ti = floor((c /2)) + b;
            %
            %               c = ((long int)wi * (long int)fr[j]);
            %               c = c >> 14;
            %               b = c & 0x01;
            %               ti = ti + ((c >> 1) + b);
            c = wi * fr(j+1);
            c = floor(c  / pow2(14));
            b = c & 1;
            ti = ti + (floor((c/2)) + b);
            %
            %               qr = fr[i];
            %               qi = fi[i];
            %               qr >>= 1;
            %               qi >>= 1;
            %
            %               fr[j] = qr - tr;
            %               fi[j] = qi - ti;
            %               fr[i] = qr + tr;
            %               fi[i] = qi + ti;
            qr = fr(i+1);
            qi = fi(i+1);
            qr = floor(qr/2);
            qi = floor(qi/2);

            fr(j+1) = qr - tr;
            fi(j+1) = qi - ti;
            fr(i+1) = qr + tr;
            fi(i+1) = qi + ti;
            %           }
            i = i+istep;
        end
        %       }
    end
    %
    %       --k;
    %       l = istep;
    %   }
    k=k-1;
    l=istep;
end
% }
end
```

Those in comments are the original, those aren't are the translated code

Then I simulated with this

```
function [ r ] = mfft( f )
%MFFT Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
Fs = 2048;
T = 1/Fs;
L = 2048;
t = (0:L-1)*T; 
NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L);
l = length(f);
y = 0;
for k=1:l
    y = y + sin(2*pi*f(k)*t);
end
%sound(y, Fs);
Y = fft(y,NFFT)/L;
YY = fft_2(y)/L;
[Y1 Y2] = fix_fft(y, zeros(1, L)); 
YYY = Y1+j()*Y2;
f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
plot(f, 2*abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1)), ':+b');
hold on
plot(f, 2*abs(YY(1:NFFT/2+1)), '-or');
plot(f, abs(YYY(1:NFFT/2+1)), '--*g');
hold off
r=0;

end
```

Basically create a simple sine wave with a specific frequency (say 400Hz)

The expected output of the FFT should be a spike at 400 only, which the builtin FFT function agrees but the other codes didn't

Here's the output graph

[image: output graph]

The blue line is from builtin function and is what expected

The red line is the above code which, well, looks pretty good except there is a spike elsewhere with higher amplitude

The green line is absolute mess

I tried checking the program several times but to no avail

Did I ported them wrong or somehow I can fix them?

Comment: couldn't you use the highly optimized `FFTW` package, instead of re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: not sure I can use that on an MCU? Also, I'm trying to make it as time efficient as possible, cycle-wise

Comment: Which micro controller? Have you looked for code already written from them from the manufacturer and/or other users?

Comment: yeah, I found a pre written code, but when I tried to simulate the code in matlab, the result is just wrong

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to approach this problem, and a programmer should try all of them.  First, an FFT is an optimization of a Fourier Transform, so as a first step code a Fourier Transform.  That is, don't do an FFT, just do a FT directly.

These days an FT is not as slow as you might think.  Unless the project needs to  transform something like 10,000 data points in less than a few milliseconds.  Also, an FT, compared to an FFT, is simple and easy to debug.

Doing this for a problem provides a baseline, that is, the correct answer.  This is important because when you work on the FFT how do you know if the problem is in the code for the FFT or that the data is correct and just giving you an unexpected, but correct, answer.

Next, use a pre-written package to do an FFT.  Scan the web, I know there are packages written in C that do FFTs.

Third, if you just have to write your own FFT then do so.  But only if tasks (1) or (2) don't meet your requirements.  It will be difficult to out-do any pre-written FFT packages.

You will learn much along this path.